# Does $\gcd(r, \sigma(r)) = 2r - \sigma(r)$ always hold when $r$ is deficient-perfect?

Tags: divisibility, gcd-and-lcm, divisor-sum, arithmetic-functions, perfect-numbers

Let $\sigma(x)$ denote the *sum of divisors* of the positive integer $x$.  A number $r$ is called *deficient-perfect* if $(2r - \sigma(r)) \mid r$.

Here is my question:

> Does $\gcd(r, \sigma(r)) = 2r - \sigma(r)$ always hold when $r$ is deficient-perfect?

**MY ATTEMPT**

Since $r$ is deficient-perfect, then $(2r - \sigma(r)) \mid r$.  Also, by [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3308889/28816), then we have $(2r - \sigma(r)) \mid \sigma(r)$.  So, $2r - \sigma(r)$ is a common divisor between $r$ and $\sigma(r)$.  How do I show that it is *always* the *greatest* common divisor?  This is where I get stuck.

Comment: Any common divisor of $r,s$ that is a linear combination $\, m r + n s\,$ is necessarily the *greatest* common divisor - see the linked dupe.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

Suppose that $d$ is a common divisor between $r$ and $\sigma(r)$.  Then $d \mid r$ and $d \mid \sigma(r)$, from which it follows that
$$d \mid (2r - \sigma(r)).$$

*Thus $2r - \sigma(r)$ is the greatest common divisor between $r$ and $\sigma(r)$.*

That is,
$$\gcd(r,\sigma(r))=2r-\sigma(r).$$

**QED (?)**

Comment: Note that $(2r - \sigma(r)) \leq r$ and $(2r - \sigma(r)) \leq \sigma(r)$, equality occurring if and only if $r=1$.